# HTML button not working in table rows jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('table td').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "Sellbtn") {
      var sell = prompt("Enter the amount you wish to sell");
      //problem is here i guess
      $(this).parent('tr').cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt($(this).parent('tr').cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;
    } else if (e.target.id === "Deletebtn") {
      return false;
    } else {
      var ask = prompt("Input");
      $(this).html(ask);
    }
  });
});
```

I have a table with several rows each row has two buttons (Sell and Delete). What i want is when I click on the sell button of a row it gets me the prompt and then the amount entered should get subtracted from the number in cell[4] of that ROW and change the amount in cell[4] to this new amount. This doesn't work obviously so what should i do?
And by the way this code gives me the error: Cannot read property '4' of undefined.

Comment: Where do you think `.cells` comes from?

Comment: the error is telling you that $(this).parent('tr').cells is undefined. try console.log( $(this).parent('tr') ) to see if there is a cells property on this object

Comment: The `cells` property is not standard jQuery. Are you getting that from a plugin? The way I would recommend getting a particular table cell is: `$(this).parent().children('td').eq(4).text()`. (There's no need to filter the parent -- there's only one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly then something like this should work:

```
var td4 = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)");
td4.html(parseInt(td4.text()) - sell);
```

The problem with your code is that `$(this).parent('tr').cells` is undefined. Also, instead of using `.innerHTML` (which only works on Javascript objects) you need to use `.html()`, which works on jQuery selections.